# R - Filter rows by columns - column names contained in an other dataframe

Tags: r

An other basic question, but I can't seem to find a solution.

Take mtcars as an example.
I would like to know the number of rows, where vs AND am are above 0.5.
AND

```
df<- mtcars
x <- subset(mtcars, (vs > 0.5) & (am > 0.5))
```

OR

```
df<- mtcars
x <- subset(mtcars, (vs > 0.5) | (am > 0.5))
```

Easy so far.

Now I would like to vary exactly which column I want to use for filtering. And the column names I want are contained in an other dataframe. How can I do the filtering? How can I do it so that the column names are compared with OR or AND - that is all the column-row pairs are compared or either column-row pair.

```
df<- mtcars
colnames <- c("vs","am")
x <- subset(mtcars, mtcars[,colnames] > 0.5)
```

Does not give right answer...
Thanks for help!

Comment: The AND version can be done with `dplyr::filter_at(mtcars, colnames, ~ . > 0.5)`.

Comment: This is great. Is there a way to use filter_at with variables at both 'ends', like: `filter_at(mtcars, colnames, ~ . > values)` where values is a list of a few values (integers). I tried and it runs but gives the wrong results.

Comment: I found the answer...OMG....I know so little...

Answer (score 0):

Not the smartest solution using basic R, but I hope you understand the way:

`mtcars[apply(mtcars[,colnames] > 0.5,1,function(x){ifelse(TRUE %in% x, TRUE, FALSE)}),]`